# Database can't be opened

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, error-handling

I get this error message whenever I try to get into my SQL Server using Visual Studio:

> The database *dbPath* cannot be opened because it is version 869. This server supports version 852 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported.
>   Could not open new database *dbPath*. CREATE DATABASE is aborted.
>   An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file *dbPath* failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

Can you please tell me what should I do to fix this error?

Comment: You're trying to restore a SQL Server 2017 database on SQL Server 2016; you can't "fix" the error. You need to update to SQL Server 2017 to be able to restore the database or have the person who supplied you the back up script the entire database out instead.

Comment: List of SQL Server Internal Database Versions
https://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/2014/01/sql-server-internal-database-versions.html